# How to POST a cUrl request the right way?

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm trying to POST a request to [name.com API](https://www.name.com/api-docs/Domains#CheckAvailability) and check domain availability in PHP. I have a simple test request really. I've gone through their Docs and API and the error I receive does not seem to have a solution. Has anyone been using their API in the past? What am I doing wrong?

**choose_domain.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['domain'])){
    //get domain mae 
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    //
    //
    $url = 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability';
    $fields = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'token' => $name_token,
                'domainNames' => array($domain)
            );
    
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    //
    //
    //
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //
    //
    //
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    
    //execute post
    $result_domain = curl_exec($ch);
    
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

**API response**

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated"}
```

According to their [API](https://www.name.com/api-docs/) this error means following :

> The URL Request has a trailing period (Period after name.com) EXAMPLE:
> https://api.dev.name.com./v4/domains . Or, the password has been
> entered but not the username, or vice versa.

This is simply not true and not the case with my codes. There are no trailing period.

Comment: `Or, the password has been entered but not the username, or vice versa.` check what `$username` and `$password` contains

Comment: @Berto99: thanks for your input. I checked the url with 'echo $fields_string' and everything is there. I even logged in my account with username and password and it's working.

Comment: please post what is echoing (obv obscure username and password)

Comment: @Berto99 : $fields_string echo this `username=myusername&password=mypassword&token=mytoken&domainNames%5B0%5D=domain.com`

Comment: Check `https://www.name.com/api-docs/Domains#CheckAvailability`  the data for `domainNames` seems to be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're sending the username and password in the wrong format. The API endpoint is expecting in the format of BASICAUTH `username and password` used for authentication as mentioned at https://www.name.com/api-docs/Domains#CheckAvailability but you're sending as raw or say body data.

Instead, you have to send your `username and password` as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

so your complete code will look like:

```
if(isset($_POST['domain'])) {
 
    //get domain mae 
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];

    $url = 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability';
    $fields = array(
                'token' => $name_token,
                'domainNames' => array($domain)
            );
    
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    
    //execute post
    $result_domain = curl_exec($ch);
    
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}
```